# Ansible syntax error when using variable in become_user

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible 2.0.1.0.

In my `main.yml` I have this task:

```
- name: hoge
  hosts: hoge2
  connection: docker
  become: yes
  become_user: {{ansible_user}}
```

When executing, I get this error message:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

The error appears to have been in '/Users/fuga/Docker/ansible/main.yml': line 16, column 17, but maybe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  become: yes
  become_user: {{ansible_user}}
                ^ here
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In YAML a `{` starts a dictionary. Therefore you need to quote the expression.

```
become_user: "{{ansible_user}}"
```

See [Gotchas in the Ansible YAML docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas).

Comment: Problem could be resolved in your favor.Thank you udondan!