# Ansible become_user with variable

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible 2.1.0.0

I try to use become_user with a variable in a task, but I receive the following message:

```
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'ansible_user' is undefined"}
```

The task executing this is

```
- name: Config git user name
  git_config: name=user.name scope=global value={{ ansible_host }}
  become: Yes
  become_user: "{{ansible_user}}"
```

And the playbook has the following line to define the remote user:

```
- name: Foo
  hosts: foo
  vars:
    http_port: 80
  remote_user: admin
```

I've seen [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273560/syntax-error-when-using-variable-in-become-user) which seems to be the same problem, but this does not work for me.

I have seen also [a set_fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580085/accessing-remote-user-variable) solution but I would like to use the remote_user var if possible so no extra lines must be added if a playbook already has the remote_user var set.

Does anyone know how to do this or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where does your ansible_user come from? I can see the remote_user but not ansible_user. try `become_user: "{{remote_user}}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that:

```
- name: Foo
  hosts: foo
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    my_user: admin
  remote_user: "{{my_user}}"
```

then:

```
- name: Config git user name
  git_config: name=user.name scope=global value={{ ansible_host }}
  become: Yes
  become_user: "{{my_user}}"
```

Comment: This works great!
As a side note I find strange to have to use an extra var / extra line to set the remote_user var, but for my current needs it fits perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it:

```
become_user: "{{ansible_ssh_user}}"
```

In fact the `remote_user: admin` is another way of defining the variable ansible_ssh_user, I dont know why remote_user is not accessible as a variable, but what I know is that when you set remote_user, it changes the variable `ansible_ssh_user`

Not sure if it's a clean solution though, but it works

Comment: No, still failing although ansible_ssh_user is a valid var in my tasks.

If the task uses this variable like that:

`- file:
    dest=/var/www
    mode=0755
    owner={{ansible_ssh_user}}
    state=directory`

Works perfectly. However, if I use this var as become_user: "{{ansible_ssh_user}}" it fails with that message.
In fact I already use ansible_ssh_user var for other tasks.

Comment: After re-reading that, I think that you could use ansible_ssh_user everywhere **except** for become_user, because that's where you set "admin"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem thrying to use `{{ ansible_ssh_user }}`

```
fatal: [xxx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'become_user' has an
invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was:
'ansible_user' is undefined"}
```

I fixed this error using this approach:

```
- name: Backups - Start backups service
  shell:
    cmd: systemctl --user enable backups.service && systemctl --user restart backups.service
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: "{{ lookup('env','USER') }}"
```

I hope this helps.